# Jquery Datepicker with Ruby on Rails does not work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I want to use the jquery datepicker for my Ruby on Rails Application. I have done everything like in this railscasts calendar [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndBKSjAbemo), but it just does not work. 
My textfield is still a normal text_field and no calendar pops up.

gemfiles: `gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'`
PS: I have even downgraded the version, but it is still not working

`application.js`:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require_tree
```

`application.css`:

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

`bikes.js`:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#bike_available_from').datepicker(dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy')
```

`bike#new` view:

```
<%= f.text_field :available_from %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<%= f.date_select :available_from, id: 'bike_available_from' %>
```

Comment: I switched to the bootstrap datepicker and this seems to work. I heard that the jquery datepicker has a problem with turbolink. But thank you for your help.